# how to line break in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```php
($message = 'EmailAddress : ' . $username . '-Accessed on : '.date("Y-m-d") . '-Time : ' . $datetime .'';)
```

This is my code it's made for sending messages to mailing someone using my login form. result going on like this (EmailAddress: dula@gmail.com-Accessed on 2021-02-23-Time: 10:59 AM) email data and time now I need to line break for before (Accessed on) I used `<br\> \r\n` but it's not working can you help me, someone, please...

```php
($message = 'EmailAddress : ' . $username . '-Accessed on : '.date("Y-m-d") . '-Time : ' . $datetime .'';)
```

for this code how to used line break inside this code ?

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail, what is your application build with (framework, for example)? Is it laravel, or vanilla PHP? Can you include more details about your server configuration regarding mailing?

Comment: I'm using WordPress

Answer (score 1):

You can use `p` element to automatically creates a new line.

```php
$message = '<p>EmailAddress : '.$username.'</p><p>-Accessed on : '.date("Y-m-d") . '-Time : ' . $datetime .'</p>';
```

And set the headers to `Content-Type` to `text/html`.

```php
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

Comment: i use it but it's not work friend this is the result (<p>EmailAddress : dula@gmail.com</p><p>-Accessed on : 2021-02-23-Time : 11:58 AM</p>)

Comment: the same result I don't understand why is it not work

Answer (score 0):

/* i think you suppose to use Content-Type is text/html for **br** tag when sending mail  */

Comment: sorry I don't understand it please show me some example

Comment: please share you email related code snippet